# Bootstrap: Simple navigation align issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to align the "Register or Login" part of this beside the main top nav just like the image.  I suppose I could have another `ul` but that's probably not the best way to do it.

This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <div class="logo">
            Logo
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">JOBS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CANDIDATES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CLIENTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How would you recommend I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your ul after your final li add a span. Within that span you can add your register button Register and your LOGIN. Doing this will allow those to be seperate from the other list items, but they will also collapse. You will need to do some styling to your button to get it to look like the Register button in the picture and will need to vertically align your span.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.